# Create form for multiple models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very new to Rails so sorry in advance if this is a fairly obvious question.

I need to make a form that can create records for multiple models in Rails. My models are categories of grocery-store items: Produce, Meat, Dairy, etc.

In my create form, I want the user to be able to create a product by selecting which model it belongs to and then have the controller insert the record into the appropriate DB table.

so my questions are:

- should I still define each model as a resource?
- is it possible to use one controller to add, update, delete for all of the product models?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just making a category column in your items model? If not you could use active record associations to accomplish something like this. See the documentation at:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html